# Efficient multidimensional numerical integration in R and C++

Tags: numerics, c++, integral-equations, r

I'm trying to perform a 4-dimensional numerical integration in `R` using a function I wrote in `C++` code which is then sourced in `R` using the `Rcpp` package.

Below there is my code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]
#define EIGEN_PERMANENTLY_DISABLE_STUPID_WARNINGS
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace Numer;

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double gaussian_free_diffusion(double x,double x0, double sigma, double t) {
  double pi = 2 * acos(0.0);
  double a1 = (1/sqrt(2.0 * pi * sigma * t));
  double b1 = exp(-pow((x - x0), 2.0)/(2.0 * sigma * t));
  double res = a1 * b1;
  return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double integral_CppFunctionCUBATURE(NumericVector Zt_pos, const double& xA0, const double& xB0, const double& yA0,
   const double& yB0, const double& t1, const double& sigma){

  double xAt_pos = Zt_pos[0];
  double xBt_pos = Zt_pos[1];
  double yAt_pos = Zt_pos[2];
  double yBt_pos = Zt_pos[3];

  double temp_pbxA = gaussian_free_diffusion(xAt_pos, xA0, sigma,t1);
  double temp_pbxB = gaussian_free_diffusion(xBt_pos, xB0, sigma, t1);
  double temp_pbyA = gaussian_free_diffusion(yAt_pos, yA0, sigma,t1);
  double temp_pbyB = gaussian_free_diffusion(yBt_pos, yB0, sigma, t1);

  return (temp_pbxB * temp_pbyB) * (temp_pbxA * temp_pbyA);

};
```

`integral_CppFunctionCUBATURE` is the function I use with `cubintegrate`. In R, I would then do:

sourceCpp('./myCppcode.cpp')

```
xA0<-3
xB0<-2
yA0<-5
yB0<-10
t<-500
sigma<-1


cubature::cubintegrate(integral_CppFunctionCUBATURE,lower=rep(-1000,4), upper=rep(1000,4),
                       xA0=xA0, xB0=xB0, yA0=yA0,yB0=yB0, t1=t, sigma=sigma,method='cuhre')$integral
```

Result: 0.9999978

The multidimensional integration takes about 4 sec, but I would like to speed it up as much as possible, since when I run the multidimensional integration on several xA0 values this can take quite some time. Do you have any suggestion on how I could improve the speed of the code?

And also, would you suggest an alternative way to perform fast 4-dimensional integration in `C++`/`Rcpp`?

Comment: Several points to mention here, better post this question on codereview. First, in the function, use constexpr pi and don't use the pow function. Second, is it really about this function, is is it just an example? Because this function is separable into 4 one-dimensional integrations, so there is no need for a cubature.

Comment: DaveHigh is right about this particular integrand being separable, take advantage of that. In general a scheme and its speed will depend on the accuracy you need and the nature of the integrand.

Comment: @davidhigh I have replace pi with M_PI, instead of constexpr pi. Is it equivalent for gaining in speed? Also, I replaced pow with a multiplication. Concerning the function, you are right that this is mostly an example, close to the function I'm working on. The only difference is that instead of being 4 gaussian functions, they are 2 gaussian function and 2 'distorted' diffusion functions, and I also multiply another function which uses the 4 variables of the integral. Your suggestion on separability of the integrand into 4 one-dimensional integrations is still valid?

Comment: Why don't you use the RcppNumericalIntegration package?